# Custom release-start, release-end messages in a custom Bitbucket's step

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I'm using `gitflow-maven-plugin:1.20.0` by `alexsandr-m` in my `pom.xml` file which is trigger via' Bitbucket's pipelines.

I configured the plugin as follow:

```
..
..
  <plugin>
      <groupId>com.amashchenko.maven.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>gitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${gitflow-maven-plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
         <commitMessages>
            <releaseFinishMessage>T1</releaseFinishMessage>
            <releaseFinishMergeMessage>T2</releaseFinishMergeMessage>
            <releaseStartMessage>T3</releaseStartMessage>
            <releaseVersionUpdateMessage>T4</releaseVersionUpdateMessage>
         </commitMessages>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
...
..
```

In my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file I do:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
   feature/*:
      ..
   develop:
      ...
   master: 
      ...
   release-to-AWS:
      - step:
          name: Release
          oidc: true
          caches:
            - maven
          script:
            - mvn -B gitflow:release-start -DpushRemote=true 
            - mvn -B gitflow:release-finish -DkeepBranch=true
```

It all works well, except printing out my custom message when executing the `release-to-AWS` step in the pipelines.
It does print the custom message when it works on `develop` or `master` or `feature` , *BUT* not the custom step, any idea??

Thank you so much!